# Why isn't my dashboard working with grid?

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to grid but I would like to know why this isn't working? (The feed needs to be below the feed input)

I have tried all I know, but it always ends up being at the bottom or on the right. As I said before, I'm new to grid and I would love some help :)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 20px;
}

#userdisplay {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#feed-input {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#feed {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="userdisplay"></div>
  <div id="feed-input"></div>
  <div id="feed"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the template
`.item {grid-column: <start-line> / <end-line> | <start-line> / span <value>;   grid-row: <start-line> / <end-line> | <start-line> / span <value>; }`

Comment: The whole thing breaks when I do that

Comment: @YosiLeibman, pleaes edit your answer to fix it instead of commenting on it.